# Funny issue while passing a value by HTTPHeaderField

Tags: php, swift, http-headers

I am trying to pass a number of values with spaces and special characters from a Swift program to a php script by attributing them to HTTPHeaderFields with code of the kind:

```
let theRequest=NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:urlString)!, cachePolicy:.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                    timeoutInterval:100.0)
theRequest.addValue(self.name, forHTTPHeaderField: "name")
theRequest.addValue(self.abbot, forHTTPHeaderField: "abbot")
theRequest.addValue(self.address, forHTTPHeaderField: "address")
theRequest.addValue(self.email!, forHTTPHeaderField: "email")
theRequest.addValue(self.phone!, forHTTPHeaderField: "phone")
theRequest.addValue(self.website!, forHTTPHeaderField: "website")
```

to be received by the php script with:

```
$name=$_SERVER['HTTP_NAME'];
$abbot=$_SERVER['HTTP_ABBOT'];
$address=$_SERVER['HTTP_ADDRESS'];
$email=$_SERVER['HTTP_EMAIL'];
$phone=$_SERVER['HTTP_PHONE'];
$website=$_SERVER['HTTP_WEBSITE'];
```

This mechanism works for all the variables, but for the address one. When I execute the call I get error:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_ADDRESS in /var/www/html/iPhone/iPuja/insertMonastery.php on line 9

in the php script; I tried changing the name of address to other strings in the case HTTP_ADDRESS were a reserved word, but to no avail. What could be the issue instead?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact I did not URLEncode the string. Once using:

```
theRequest.addValue(self.address.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!, forHTTPHeaderField: "address")
```

The value went through; for some reason instead of giving an error when sending non-urlencoded strings with special characters, nothing is sent instead.
On the php script I had to of course urldecode the thing and also set:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

in order to cope with the accented strings and other special characters.